# Get next 30 day sales from customer visit date in SQL Server

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

Please help me with the SQL query of getting the next 30 days sales from the customer visit on website.

Looking for report automation where i can track the sales if it happens within 30 days of the visit.

Table A - It contains visit date & id
Table B - It contains sales record with date & id

Problem - Unable to apply filter where it automatically check from table B & show result if it get sold within 30 days of the visit.

Please help.

Comment: MySQL is not the same thing as SQL Server. Don't spam the tags just to be noticed.

Answer (score 1):

Well, providing the table structure would have helped a lot, Here I am assuming the following about the tables:

1. `visitors` table - contains `id` and `visited_date`
2. `sales` table - contains `id`, `visitor_id` and `sold_date`

Now, to get a list of sales that happened withing 30 days of the visit, we can take the help of [`DATEDIFF` function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/datediff-transact-sql):

```
SELECT 
    visitors.id,
    visitors.visited_date,
    sales.id,
    sales.sold_date,
    DATEDIFF(DAY, visitors.visited_date, sales.sold_date) AS sold_within
FROM
    visitors
        JOIN
    sales ON (visitors.id = sales.visitor_id)
WHERE
    DATEDIFF(DAY, visitors.visited_date, sales.sold_date) <= 30;
```